# Use Spring Data repositories to fill in test data

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, test-data

I'd like to ask whether it is alright to use apps repositories(Spring Data based) to fill in testing data. I know I can use sql file with data, but sometimes I need something more dynamical. I find writing sql or datasets definitions cumbersome(and hard to maintain in case of schema change). Is there anything wrong with using app repositories? There are all basic CRUD operations already there. Note we are talking especially about integration testing.

I feel it is kind of weird to use part of app to test itself. Maybe I can create another set of repositories to be used in test contexts.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, maybe you would like to explain more clearly. App repositories / Dynamical what are you really trying to achieve.

Comment: Just fill the database for testing without using plain sql or any other dataset/xml files.

Comment: Then you already answered using spring-data-apis for that.

Comment: I know the question is if this is somehow acceptable for integration testing or if it breaks some best practises.

Comment: Well I would recommend, if you use APIs for setting up data that client is going to use. That would be a true integration test then. (Maybe REST API or something else). Precisely think from the perspective as if user is performing those actions.

Comment: There can be problem to set the DB to exact state. Maybe the API allows for that, but in multiple steps. Maybe I just want to call service and not to setup the whole API backend for the test. But I see your point, I have been using MockMVC for this and have been calling /user/create then /user/update and /user/1 to verify the result. You need to setup the whole context. By using only the repositories I can for example skip MockMVC.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is absolutely nothing wrong with using Spring Data repositories to create test data.

I even prefer that since it often allows for simpler refactoring.

As with any use of JPA in tests you need to keep in mind that JPA implementations are a write-behind cache. You probably want to flush and clear the `EntityManager` after setting up the test data, so that you don't get anything from the 1st level cache that really should come from the database. Also, this ensures data is actually written to the database and problems with that will surface.

You might be interested in a [couple of articles about testing with Hibernate](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/03/13/testing-databases-with-junit-and-hibernate-part-1-one-to-rule-them/). They don't use Spring Data, but it would work with Spring Data JPA just the same.

Comment: Would you also recommend any pattern? Manage flush manually or wrap somehow the repository calls in separate transaction?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to some articles I once wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to use `Flyway` to setup your databases and use [Flyway test extension](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions) for integration testing.

So that you can do something like that:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/context/simple_applicationContext.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    FlywayTestExecutionListener.class})
@Test
@FlywayTest(locationsForMigrate = {"loadmsql"}) // execution once per class
public class MethodTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

  @BeforeClass
  @FlywayTest(locationsForMigrate = {"loadmsql"}) // execution once per class
  public static void beforeClass() {
    // maybe some additional things
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  @FlywayTest(locationsForMigrate = {"loadmsql"}) // execution before each test method
  public void beforeMethod() {
    // maybe before every test method
  }


  @Test
  @FlywayTest(locationsForMigrate = {"loadmsql"}) // as method annotation
  public void simpleCountWithoutAny() {
    // or just with an annotation above the test method where you need it
  }
```

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. I'd like to omit the use of any sql, xml, flyway migration file. I just want to call userRepository.createUser() and then call the service to update this user. Then after just userRepository.findAll() and verify the user has been updated. UserRepository will be part of the application anyway so I want to use it for data preparation/verification.

Comment: Actually flyway supports java-based migrations, which is close to what I need, but you will need to write sql inside. I don't think it is possible to call repository inside of such migration.It is close to [Spring test jdbc support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-support-jdbc)